# Copy image file from one location to a different location using the file picker

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an image control named `itemImage` set to `ItemImage` field on the table.
I am using a `file picker` to browse to a location and copy an image then save it to a different location, and rename it using a textbox value, then add its full location to the table.

**Question:**

Does the `image control` on access work with `.jpg` files? or do I need to convert to `.bmp`? if so how do I maintain the file extension when I copy a file from one location to another?
Is there a better or more efficient way of accomplishing this kind of task?

My current attempt copies the image but does not display a known `.bmp` image on the form.
Please see below:

```
Private Sub itemImage_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo 0
Dim ofd As Object
Dim fso As Object
Dim theFile As String
Dim theFileLocation As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim fullFileName As String
Dim theFileName As String

Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(3)
ofd.AllowMultiSelect = False
ofd.Show
If ofd.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
theFile = Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1, Len(ofd.SelectedItems(1)))
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filePath = ofd.SelectedItems(1)

CopyImage filePath, Me.donationNumber & Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "."))

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblDonatedItems SET ItemImage =  '" & Application.CurrentProject.Path + "\ItemImages\" + donationNumber.Value + Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), ".")) & "' WHERE DonationNumber = '" & Me.donationNumber.Value & "'", dbFailOnError

Else
   MsgBox "Image update Cancel!"
End If

End Sub

Sub CopyImage(filePath As String, fileName As String)
Dim fs As Object
Dim images_path As String
images_path = CurrentProject.Path & "\ItemImages\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CopyFile filePath, images_path & fileName
Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Image control can certainly use jpg. Can't simply change file extension of image file name and expect the image to be readable. Maintain the same file extension by extracting from original name and setting a variable then concatenating that variable to new file name.

Comment: The CopyImage sub could be simpler. Unlike CopyFile, FileCopy does not require FSO object. Instead of opening a recordset object, could just run an UPDATE action SQL.

Comment: @June7 The extension extraction part is the one I am having problem with. Surely an UPDATE action is better than using recordset. I have updated code and removed the CopyImage sub completely. Please see updated code. Regards

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having? You already understand string manipulation functions. Just use them to extract extension. So instead of `& ".bmp"`, like:  `& Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "."))`. You are allowing multiple items to be selected in FileDialog but then only run copy if count = 1. Should only one selection be allowed?

Comment: Why still setting fso object variable if using FileCopy?

Comment: @June7 I simply don't know how to use FileCopy as it is all new to me. I have considered going back to CopyFile and with your help, the code now updates the table and copies the file well. However, the control still does not display the `.jpg` image. Please see updated code.

Comment: @June7 I can see the `.jpg` i am talking about is actually a actually a `.jpeg` file. I wonder why the jpeg file does not readable on the image control where as the .jpg file is readable.

Comment: That's not the question you originally asked. I am not able to get jpeg to work either. Guessing will have to use an image editor app to convert.

Comment: @June7 I see, I have noticed that if I change the file extension by renaming the `.jpeg` file and changing the extension to `.jpg` the image control reads it just fine. I'm still curious about using `FileCopy` to properly accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the actual issue is with jpeg file extension, not jpg. Access is not rendering jpeg image in Image control. I also observe that simply changing file extension from jpeg to jpg allows Access to render the file. So consider:

```
strExt = Mid(ofd.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(ofd.SelectedItems(1), "."))
If strExt = ".jpeg" Then strExt = ".jpg"
```

Or don't bother with strExt and If Then conditional and just use Replace() function. Also, using FileCopy would be like:
`FileCopy filePath, images_path & Replace(fileName, ".jpeg", ".jpg")`